# How do I get JMeter Junit Request Sampler to run @BeforeClass?

Tags: jmeter, junit4

I have the following Test class...

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class AdminSpecTest extends BaseTest{
    @BeforeClass
    public static void getLogin(){
        System.out.println("getLogin");
        ...
    }
    @Test
    public void testAdminPage(){
        System.out.println("testAdmin");
        ...
    }
}
```

When I try to create a JUnit sampler in JMeter I run the test and it fails. In the terminal window I see...

> testAdmin

but there is no getLogin. Why isn't BeforeClass getting called? Can I get this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Accoding to JMeter's [JUnit](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) you can use `@Before` instead for setup before test executes.

> The following JUnit4 annotations are recognised:
>
> @Before
>   treated the same as setUp() in JUnit3
>
> @BeforeClass, @AfterClass
>   treated as test methods so they can be run independently as required

Comment: I need @BeforeEach because I need it once per all tests in the class so this won't work

Comment: As I understood you need to execute one test at a time

Comment: This isn't true what in my post suggested that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to do this, but this solution involves adding another class at least temporarily while you are performance testing with JMeter. You then use this class to call the other test class (AdminSpecTest). Make sure you select this new class and method in JMeter's Junit Sampler dropdowns.

```
package test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;

public class TestRunner
{
    public TestRunner()
    {
        
    }
    
    @Test
    public void runTests()
    {
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        junit.run(AdminSpecTest.class);
    }
}
```